# Nesting JSON query result in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql-server, json

I have the following test data:

```
create table #T (MeterID int,[Description] varchar(255),[Status] varchar(55),Date datetime2(0),Reading int)
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:13',105678
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:14',105682
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:15',105684
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:16',105685
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:17',105686
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:18',105688
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:19',105688
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:20',105689
insert into #T select 4201544,'Home test','Active','2016/03/23 06:21',105690
```

which I extracted into the desired JSON as follows:

```
select
    [MeterID],
    [Description],
    [Status],
    (select
        [Date],
        [Reading]
    from
        #T
    for JSON path) [Readings]
from
    #T
group by
    MeterID,
    [Description],
    [Status]
for JSON path, ROOT ('Data')
```

In this case there are very few rows and the query executes fast.  However, in production this will be applied over many more rows.  It seems inefficient to query #T twice.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?  I tried unsuccessfully to apply aliases on a single query of #T.

Comment: Check query plan, there is a chance that SQL will optimize that query for you (otherwise let's try with a CTE)

Comment: Query plan shows that #T is scanned twice (without indexes on test data).  What is you idea with CTE?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid two scans. Maybe this query will work better:

```
with groups AS (
select
    [MeterID],
    [Description]
    from  #T) 
select groups.[MeterID], groups.[Description], [Status], [Date], [Reading]
    from groups join #T Readings on groups.MeterID = Readings.MeterID
for json AUTO, ROOT ('Data')
```

With FOR JSON AUTO you will have nested results (still with two joins), but you will avoid costly UDX and sort (I see that cost of sort operator in the plan is ~60% compared to 20% for table scans).